# DOM Explorer not working in VS2015 RC

Tags: cordova, dom, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2015

The DOM Explorer is not working for me in VS 2015 RC. (Version 14.0.22823.1)

It looks like this: (just one big button)

[image: DOM Explorer error VS2015RC]

I have gone through the options/settings but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Have anybody experienced the same issue/problem or maybe an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, I work on the team that builds the DOM Explorer in VS.  It would be great if you could answer a few clarifying questions: 1) What versions of Windows & IE are you using? 2) What project type are you using?

Comment: Hi Andy,
1. Windows 7 Enterprise and IE 10 (10.0.9200.17377)
2. Apache Cordova Apps (under JavaScript)

Comment: The DOM Explorer in VS 2015 only works against IE11. To be sure though could you try the scenario again and then look in the event viewer for Watson Error Report from Visual Studio and post the info (if you're comfortable publishing the contents - otherwise you can email me)? Some more details on that in the "Watson Bucket ID" section of this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/02/08/how-to-investigate-and-report-visual-studio-issues.aspx

Comment: Hi Andy,

From the eventlog (ID 1001):

Fault bucket 3043773, type 28
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: ScriptedSandbox64.exe
P2: 14.0.22823.1
P3: 55389b04
P4: mshtml.dll
P5: 10.0.9200.17377
P6: 5566427a
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000002ec15d
P9: 
P10: 

I can mail you the Report.wer file if you need this as well. What's is your mail address?

And thanks for helping me/us.

Comment: Thanks! I've found the bug on our end and have made a note. There's not likely to be a workaround in the mean time. Could you update to IE11? That should address the issue.

Comment: Hi Andy. It's not an option to update IE at the moment - but thanks for you help.

Comment: Just a short update: I updated to IE11 and it's working fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Internet Explorer.

I can't find system requirements for the DOM Explorer anywhere, but I suspect it requires IE 11. I had this same issue (with IE 10) until I ran Windows Update and [restored](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/restore-and-install-hidden-updates) the hidden IE 11 update.

---

According to @Andy Sterland in the comments, there is a bug when using VS 2015's DOM Explorer with IE 10. The only workaround at this time is to update to IE 11.