# DOM Explorer and JavaScript Console not working in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: angularjs, cordova, dom, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I've migrated my Cordova app from VS2013 to VS2015 Community, and I now find myself unable to use DOM Explorer or JavaScript Console during debugging:

[image]

The big refresh buttons do nothing, and the same happens with Microsoft's sample Angular/Cordova app: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-samples/tree/master/todo-angularjs.

This question has a similar problem: [DOM Explorer not working in VS2015 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31034027/dom-explorer-not-working-in-vs2015-rc)

But it seemed to have been fixed by an update to IE11, which I already have installed.

Has anybody else encountered this and perhaps have a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem. you can solve it on two ways:

```
1. Open chroome --> Settings--> developer tools---> console.
```

you can debug there.

2. make the restore hidden updates from `control panel--> windows updates.`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I'm debugging on a real device so Chrome dev tools won't help though. And I don't have a restore hidden updates option, I suspect it was removed in Windows 10. So unfortunately I still have the problem.

Comment: Man just update your windows, and IE 11. 
it will solve you problem.